# Truncate UILabel before it runs into another UILabel dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

Basically, I have this situation:

Two UILabels in a UITableViewCell. They're both constrained to the top of the cell. One is constrained to the left of the cell, and one is constrained to the right of the cell.

There exists a change that the UILabel on the left can run into the UILabel on the right. Is there anyway to truncate the text x points before it gets to the UILabel on the right?

Right now, I handle this by giving the UILabel on the left an explicit width that ensures it will truncate before reaching the UILabel, but the explicit width is not dynamic based on screen size. If there is a larger screen size, it might not need to be truncated. I'm new to iOS development and am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is in auto-layout. Make sure the label on the right is a fixed size, you can even change it programatically if you need to accommodate to screen size. But the thing is this one needs a width constraint. The label on the left does not have a width constraint, instead do a horizontal spacing in front of it to the cell border and from it's trailing end to the start of the label view on the right. It will widen and shrink to fit the size that's left for it.

Comment: Okay, so width constraint on the right one. Then, I do a margin constraint to the top, left and right for the left one?

Comment: Exactly! You want the one on the left to adjust to what's left for it ;)